# I'm having trouble extracting XML data from attributes and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

After doing a lot of research, I still can't figure out why this tutorial works and my code doesn't.  I'm trying to extract data from an XML attribute, and I don't know what's wrong.

Here's the working tutorial I started from:
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_getattribute

The XML file used in that tutorial is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml

Now here's my attempt to modify the code: (Note - I included the full text of the js file in the header script, so you wouldn't have to look for the file they used in the tutorial.  You can ignore the header since I didn't change anything there.)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function loadXMLDoc(dname) 
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=a");

txt=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("suggestion")[0].getAttribute("data");
document.write(txt);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the xml file I referenced:

```
http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=a
```

I've been struggling with this for a while, so if anyone has an idea of what to do, I really would appreciate it.

Comment: The demo fetches content from its own domain, your code attempts to do so from a different domain; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320511/how-do-you-get-content-from-another-domain-with-load

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load external content. You can save the file from the url in your computer first, then run the script again referencing to the local file