# Using jquery .load to load cross domain site using James Padolsey's jquery mod

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I am trying to use this mod for performing cross domain requests with jquery: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/.

The script is available at https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js.

Firstly I would like to just test the functionality of the mod performing the .load function quoted on the page:

```
$('#container').load('http://google.com'); // SERIOUSLY!
```

My simple guess on how to do this would be the following

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

        <div id="container">
        google.com should be placed here
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#container').load('http://google.com'); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work, though (just outputs google.com should be placed here).

Any help on how to change my guess to work would be most appreciated.

I have checked out [How do you get content from another domain with .load()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320511/how-do-you-get-content-from-another-domain-with-load) which seems to be almost the same content as my question, but does not answer how you could actually make the jquery mod linked work.

Comment: check your console. Haven't you got a message about google and iframe?

Comment: I assume you mean my browser console: Nothing is displayed in the console in both Chrome and IE. Changing http://google.com to the URI of another domain does not change the way the page works.