# load external (from other domain) content and exclude some div-Tags

Tags: html, iframe, external

how can I load an external website from another domain and exclude some content within div-Tags (header, menu, footer, ...).
Does anyone have a working example?

Thanks for help

Comment: If the other domain does not support CORS or JSONP you will need a proxy

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get content from another domain with .load()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320511/how-do-you-get-content-from-another-domain-with-load)

Comment: I would also suggest duplicate of that but OP seems to lack the general understanding to pull that off